# external style sheets, specifying absolute or relative paths

Tags: html, css

the href portion of the the link tag for including external stylesheets is confusing to me, especially since most folks don't use an entire URL.

For example, in

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

if I wanted to put my stylesheet in a subdirectory off wwwroot, what would be the difference in attempting to reference it via:

a) href="/someDir/mystyles.css"

b) href="./someDir/mystyles.css"

c) href="someDir/mystyles.css"

Thanks Much

Comment: only option c would do anything. http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html

Comment: option b and c are the same actually. "./" refers to the current directory.

Comment: yah, I forgot that, thanks.  But why do folks even use the "./" style.  Hmm.

Comment: I think some people are just used to it from working with *nix environments. I think it kinda looks more assuring that when you're referencing a file, it's from the current directory.

Comment: I think you're right Matt -- thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basic relative URL syntax. There is nothing CSS specific about this.

Assuming this appears in `http://example.com/foo/bar/index.html`

> `href="/someDir/mystyles.css"`

`http://example.com/someDir/mystyles.css`

> `href="./someDir/mystyles.css"`

`http://example.com/foo/bar/someDir/mystyles.css`

> `href="someDir/mystyles.css"`

`http://example.com/foo/bar/someDir/mystyles.css`

And you didn't mention `href="../someDir/mystyles.css"`

Which would be: `http://example.com/foo/someDir/mystyles.css`

Comment: Thanks, so b and c are identical it appears.  Thanks for providing a "D".  Do you have a preference on technique(s) to use?  Thanks.