# Firefox can't detect my css file, but IE can

Tags: html, css, url

Firefox can't detect my CSS file, but IE can.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Pathfinder Outage Page</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="c:\documents and settings\Desktop\Outage_Page\swanstyle.css" TYPE="text/css">
 </head>
```

Comment: Don't use an absolute, *local* path to your CSS. Just put in a relative one.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="swanstyle.css" TYPE="text/css">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use an absolute, local path to your CSS. Just put in a relative one.

So if your CSS file resides in the same directory as the HTML file, just use:

```
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF=".\swanstyle.css" TYPE="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

The location of a file on your disk is not an appropriate value for an `href` element.  If you want to pull in a file from the disk (and, again, I think in most cases you don't want to) the proper syntax is

```
<link rel=StyleSheet href="file:///c:/documents%20and%20settings/Desktop/Outage_Page/swanstyle.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Outage_Page\swanstyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

PS: use [relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235848/external-style-sheets-specifying-absolute-or-relative-paths)!

Comment: You should write what the difference is to `tag` in the question and why this change should work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UPPERCASES, and use local links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..\Outage_Page\swanstyle.css" TYPE="text/css">
```

Comment: what is the problem with uppercase tag names and attributes? (except in xhtml it is permitted to use them, even if it is conventional to use the canonical cases)

Answer (score -1):

Try including it like this:

```
<link href="file:///c:/documents and settings/Desktop/Outage_Page/swanstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```