# External CSS files won't link up with my external HTML files

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a site and I wanted to have external HTML files for different sections of the site (Nav Bar). So like you'd usually do, I linked up the HTML files together and it worked, but with the CSS files for the second file, it's a different story. I used  to link the file to the site but it for some reason did not work.

I checked to see if there were errors, still not linking. I tried using different ways of linking, notta.

The link tag I used to link the CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animations.css">
```

Below is my animations.css file:

```
/*Page Background Color Animation*/
@keyframes body {
    /*Eplepse Warning*/
    10% {background-color: yellow;}
    20% {background-color: orange;}
    30% {background-color: red;}
    40% {background-color: lightblue;}
    50% {background-color: purple;}
    60% {background-color: lightgreen;}
    70% {background-color: #DFB900;}
    80% {background-color: #CAFFAA;}
    90% {background-color: #98FF4A;}
    100% {background-color: #36FFFF;}
    /*Party in the house!!!!!*/
}
#body.animate {
    background-color: yellow;
    animation-name: body;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 8000;
}
```

Hope that you were able to know what I was saying

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!  are both the html and css in the same folder?  if not, check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7235883/4846648

Comment: You're attaching the animation to `#body`. Do you have an element with that ID? Please include the relevant HTML. We can't possibly give you a definitive answer if the question doesn't include any issues.

Comment: This all depends on where your HTML files are relative to your CSS files, and whether or not you are using a `<base href>` tag

Comment: @Tyler Roper It displays this ```Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND```

Comment: Then you're most likely linking to your stylesheet incorrectly. Please edit your question to include an example of where the files exist in relation to one another.

Answer (score -2):

First, make sure your css and html files are in the same folder, and if that doesn't work Check your browser's console and make sure you have 0 errors. No errors mean you are linking correctly and if you are using chrome, i would advice you to clear your browser's cache and try to refresh the page. I've run into a similar problem where CSS will just not update on chrome, so i hope the solution works for you.

Tip: In order to always have a fresh copy of your CSS, open up you browser's developer tools, and look for the network tab and check the Disable cache button. This will stop your browser from caching the file and you will end up with a new copy each time. Check the picture below.

[image]

Comment: OP has noted in the comments that they're getting a 404, so caching isn't the issue. Although this is helpful, it doesn't provide a definitive solution to the issue, and therefore it isn't an "answer". While helpful suggestions are appreciated, they should be left as **comments**.

Comment: My bad i did not read the comments and i am unable to comment on his question because i have less than 50 reputation points. Still new here.

Comment: No worries. Please realize though that the comment reputation threshold exists for a reason - answers should never be used as a substitute. Instead, consider answering questions that you can provide a definitive solution to.