# CSS is not working, What I do, I checked all parts and also do hard refresh but it is not working?

Tags: html, css

This is my index.html file. This is head part of result.html and the name of css is result.css which is in same folder

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="./result.css" type="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Document</title>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [external style sheets, specifying absolute or relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235848/external-style-sheets-specifying-absolute-or-relative-paths)

Comment: Share your full code so others can help you. Also bootstrap css is working right?

Answer (score 1):

Your link tag should be like this:

```html
<link href="./result.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It seems you've accidently typed `type="stylesheet"` instead of `rel="stylesheet"`

Take a look at the reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

Comment: @PathParakh does this help you?